# Google sheets returning null value for getRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

trying to code a function that, when a menu item is selected, certain data is called and duplicated at the bottom of the open sheet on a spreadsheet - currently the data is being called from an 'Examples' sheet row by row, so I'm trying to pass rowNumber through to the duplicateLastRow function - and currently on this it returns a null value and I can't figure out why.

I'm also very open to different ways of doing this, as my menu has ~80 items, and therefore 80 function definitions, and I feel like 500 lines of code is excessive to copy and paste stuff on command. Code included below, and linked sheet made public here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yOJ8VdhbkbC9vw5or4geV-mv-PCk-WA86L8-F7-WGM8/edit?usp=sharing 
The project in script editor is called copyRowFromOriginToDestination, and the script I'm working on is called testFileBlarg - Code2 script is the working but huge version of the code that I'm trying to remove dialog prompts and lines from.

Cheers much in advance!

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('testRow')
   .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Life Sciences')
   .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('NRG')
    .addItem('Highlight/Alamy', 'callHANRG') 
    ))
  .addToUi();

}

function callHANRG(rowNumber){
  duplicateLastRow(3);
}

function duplicateLastRow(rowNumber){

  var originSheetName = "Example Rows";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // This is an object that represents the open spreadsheet
  var originSheet = ss.getSheetByName(originSheetName); // This object represents the sheet we are copying FROM
  var destinationSheet = ss.getActiveSheet() // getSheetByName(destinationSheetName); // This object represents the sheet we are copying TO

  destinationSheet.insertRowAfter(destinationSheet.getLastRow()); // This adds a row to the end of the destination sheet so it doesn't fill up!

  var originRow = originSheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, originSheet.getLastColumn() ); // This object represents the row to be copied
  var destinationRow = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1); // This object represents the row we are copying to

  originRow.copyTo(destinationRow); // This actions the copying
 }
```

Comment: From what I understand from your code is that you want to write a function to copy data from one worksheet to other, correct?

Comment: yes, that is what I want, unless there is a better way to generate the data in the worksheet - I've been looking into arrays but I really know very little about all this

Comment: Check my answer, it should do then

Comment: I'm not sure how your function allows me to vary the row number by menu item selected? Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to copy data from one worksheet to other refer the code below to get started.

**Update:**

To use this function as a common function to copy data, for example -

```
function callHANRG(rowNumber){
  copy(3, "A2:I20");
}
```

And then in `Copy()` function,

```
function Copy(rowNumber, rangeToBeCopied)
{
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<SPREADSHEET_ID>');
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Front');
    var range = ss.getRange(rangeToBeCopied);
    var data = range.getValues();

   //If your copying data to different spreadsheet then only use this line or 
   //else use var ts = sss.getSheetByName('frontBackup'); and comment the two lines below.
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<SPREADSHEET_ID>');
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName('frontBackup');
    ts.getRange(rowNumber, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks quite similar to what I have I think? My problem is that I want X in  ts.getRange(X, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); to vary  by menu item selected. Currently I'm using the variable rowNumber, which doesn't seem to be passing on.

Comment: @KateSnowdon check my udpated answer